# Tuple unpacking into function with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples

Let's say I have a list of tuples and a simple function that takes two arguments:

```
a_list = [(1,6), (6,8)]
add_it(a + b)
```

I now want to unpack the tuple into the function. I know I can do it by indices:

```
l = [add_it(tup[0], tup[1]) for tup in a_list]
```

But I kinda expected this would work, too:

```
l = [add_it(a, b) for tup in a_list for a, b in tup]
```

Because this works:

```
tup = (3,5)
a, b = tup
>>> 3 5
```

Can someone point me to what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in your innermost `for` statement you are *iterating* over the tuple, so you cannot unpack it. You unpack the individual items of a sequence. If it were a tuple of pairs or a list of pairs, then it would work.

```
>>> a_list = [(1,6), (6,8)]
>>> b_list = [[(1,6)], [(6,8)]]
>>> def add_it(a, b): return a+b
...
>>> l = [add_it(a, b) for tup in a_list for a, b in tup]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> l = [add_it(a, b) for tup in b_list for a, b in tup]
>>> l
[7, 14]
```

And, as pointed out by others, it is overengineered, you only need one `for` expression in your comprehension since `a_list` is already a list of pairs:

```
>>> [add_it(a,b) for a,b in a_list]
[7, 14]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
l = [add_it(a, b) for a, b in a_list]
# or
l = [add_it(*tup) for tup in a_list]
```

because

`a, b in tup` cannot work as `tup` does not contain pairs, `a_list` does!
Translated to your nested logic that would be:

```
l = [add_it(*(x for x in tup)) for tup in a_list]
```

But that is just unnecessarily wordy.

Answer (score 2):

no need for a double loop. Just unpack in the loop arguments

```
l = [add_it(tup[0], tup[1]) for tup in a_list]
```

becomes

```
l = [add_it(a,b) for a,b in a_list]
```

note: that would work as well (unpacking arguments):

```
l = [add_it(*tup) for tup in a_list]
```

Comment: I'm sorry about posting 2 quasi-similar answers before. Everyone understood this was a technical issue :)